# Python - write the same thing of print result

Tags: python, list

I have this code below:

```
x = ["a","b","c"]
list = x
for i in list:
    x=("\nletter",i,"and\n")
    i+=i

with open("teste.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(str(x))
```

and i'm trying to write the 'x' into a file with "with open", but when i write returns:

```
('\nletter', 'c', 'and\n')
```

and should be returns:

```
letter a and


letter b and


letter c and
```

When i replace the 'x' by print() works fine, but print the result on python. Here is the code:

```
x = ["a","b","c"]
list = x
for i in list:
    print("\nletter",i,"and\n")
    i+=i
```

How i can write the print result on a file? Thanks!

Comment: Change `x=("\nletter",i,"and\n")` with `x=["\nletter",i,"and\n"]`, and also you may want to do `f.write(x.join(" "))`

Comment: your first 5 lines of code made me wonder *why* like 10 times.

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a variable name in python.

Comment: Dont use `list` as name for your datastructures. Name it `myList` or `Hugo`or whatever - but do not use names that have meaning in the pyton context like `list`, `set` , ìnt` etc. Dont use reserved words - ever. `x` is already a list - why use a second name do adress the same list and name it `list`. What you do in your first likes is akin to :  `x is [ a list of short strings]` then `list = the same things as x is` then `now x is a tuple` - multiple Times with overwritign it each time and `i +=1' which I wouldnt think of working but it does - gotta that one myself - probably some iterrator+1.

Comment: no iterator - you make 'a' to 'aa' and it will be replaced by 'b' on 2nd round etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the value of `x` each time through the loop, not appending to it. This would be much easier with the `print` function:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c"]
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    for letter in x:
        print("letter {} and".format(letter), file=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
x = ["a","b","c"]
x = ["\nletter" + i + "and\n" for i in x]

with open("teste.txt","w") as f:
    for line in x:
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit just one loop:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c"]

with open("teste.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in x[:-1]:
        f.write("letter " + i + " and" + '\n' + '\n')
    f.write("letter " + x[-1] + " and")
```

Comment: Wow, you've got: `list(x)` when `x` is already a `list`, `for i in range(len(y)):`, **and** `str(y[i])` when each element is already a string!!

Comment: You still cast `x` to `list` which is unnecessary. `for i in x[:-1]` works exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration of the for loop, you are **recreating** your variable, instead of **adding** your values into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the first list to create another:

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
sentences = []
for i in letters:
    sentences.append("\nletter " + i + " and\n")

with open("teste.txt", "w") as f:
    for sentence in sentences:
        f.write(sentence)
```

or in a more terse fashion:

```
with open("teste.txt", "w") as f:
    for letter in letters:
        f.write("\nletter " + letter + " and\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
list = x
```

So later on changing `x`, you are also changing the `list`...